# fire action only after notification appears (swift3)

Tags: ios, date, swift3, notifications, action

My code uses a `datePicker`, that when the `datePicker` is changed and matches the current date of the user device. It fires a notification. However the `AVSpeechUtterance` I am using fires as soon as the `datePickers` time is changed not when the notification appears. I would like the `AVSpeechUtterance` and notification to be be fired at the same time.

```
import UIKit
import  AVFoundation
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: Any) {
    let c = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    c.title = "Lets Roll"
    c.subtitle  = "s"
    c.body = "d"

    let begin = AVSpeechUtterance(string: " Hello ")

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    begin.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    begin.rate = 0.08

    synthesizer.speak(begin)

    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: datePicker.date )
    let t = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    let r = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "any", content: c, trigger: t)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(r, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}}
```

APP DELEAGATE

```
  import AVFoundation
   import UIKit
   import UserNotifications

 enum NotificationName: String {
case mySpeechNotification
 }


   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Ops, error trying to get authorization")
            } else {
                if !granted {
                    print("Dude, let me use notifications!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)     {
     print("Oh, will present a notification, let's see the identifier: \(notification.request.identifier)")
    if (notification.request.identifier == NotificationName.mySpeechNotification.rawValue) {
        print("Speaking...")
               } else {
        print("Nothing to say...")
    }

    completionHandler(.alert)
    let begin = AVSpeechUtterance(string: " Hello ")
    begin.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    begin.rate = 0.08

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.speak(begin)


}

  }
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

You can perform your speech action when the notification is received. To achieve this you can:

If you're below iOS 10 you can use `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` on `UIAppplicatinoDelegate` and then start your speech thing.

An idea of implementation would be to check some value on the notification to make sure that is the "speech notification" you triggered.

If you're on iOS 10+ you can use the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegateExample` [here](https://github.com/henriqueiv/UNUserNotificationCenterDelegateExample) you can take a look of an example implementation.

Comment: I will give you the points if you show me how to implement this. Do I need to implement this app delegate?

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: You should put your code on the AppDelegate or any global object(like a global singleton) created before the app initialize as stated in the documentation.

Comment: I edited my question with adding a app delegate part above. The code does not speaking anything when the notification appears. With what I put in app delegate.

Comment: Just tested here and is working perfectly. I just updated the repository with code for speech, check again.

Comment: This is what the code is doing: If you hit the button and don't leave the app the speech is said but the notification does not appear. If you hit the button and leave the app the notification appears but the speech is not spoken. I don't know what is going on. Thank you so much.

Comment: To make the notification appear when the app is in foreground you must call `completionHandler(.alert)` at the end of the method. Check the updated git. If this is not what you want then edit your question with you need.

Comment: I slightly edited your code check out updated app delegate in question. This code always show the notification. It plays the speech when the user is still in the app but not when the user exits the app. All I need at this point is for the speech to be played when the user is not in the app. Thanks You.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149858/discussion-between-valcanaia-and-sam-burns).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with setting **preUtteranceDelay** for AVSpeechUtterance ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI //framework to customize the notification

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    //MARK:- Date Picker Value Changed
    func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
        let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        if selectedDate == currentDate{
            self.triggerLocalNotification()
        }
        print(selectedDate)

    }

    //MARK:- Removed all pending notifications
    func removeLocalNotification()  {
        print("Removed all pending notifications")
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [appDelegate.requestIdentifier])

    }

    //MARK:- Trigger Local Notification
    func triggerLocalNotification() {
        self.removeLocalNotification()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Title"
        content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        content.body = "Body"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: appDelegate.requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in

            if (error != nil){
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

//============AppDelegate=========

```
import UIKit
import  AVFoundation
import  UserNotifications

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let requestIdentifier = "SampleRequest" //identifier is to cancel the notification request
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Requesting Authorization for User Interactions
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
    center.delegate = self
    return true
}


extension AppDelegate:UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Tapped in notification")
}

//This is key callback to present notification while the app is in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Notification being triggered")
    let begin = AVSpeechUtterance(string: " Hello ")
    begin.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    begin.rate = 0.08
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    synthesizer.speak(begin)
    //You can either present alert ,sound or increase badge while the app is in foreground too with ios 10
    //to distinguish between notifications
       if notification.request.identifier == requestIdentifier{
            completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])
       }
    }
}
```

============

Comment: Hi, Sam Burns I have written all the code. Please check and let me know that it's work or not. In my side it's work perfectly.

Comment: what goes in the ... in app delegate?

Comment: Hi, Sam Burns. I have not written all codes of app delegate. required function and code are written for app delegate.  Add code inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and add variables and add the extension of app delegate.

Comment: I am going to give you the bounty. I think I am close to getting it to work with this I might have another question though.

Comment: Tried your code. It produced 2 error messages could you take a look at my original questions with a picture with the errors thanks.